# Would the Eldar be able to stand against the Tyranids before the fall?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I've always been Eldar and I often get upset that they threw away all they had just because they got bored (more or less)

So what would happen had the Fall never happened and we bring in these Fleets into play? Delete the Eye of Terror of course...

Could the Eldar hold their own with the Nids? Or would it just be a matter of time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your question asks could, before the [Fall of the Eldar](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Eldar), could their galaxy-spanning empire stood alone against the Tyrannid menace? The answer cannot be canon, since once the [Eldar](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Eldar) fell into hedonism and decadence, their forces were never likely to act collectively again. Their individual [Craftworlds](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Craftworld) are quite powerful, but no match for any significant confrontation of the Tyrannid.

- The reason for the Tyrannid superiority is simple. Their fleets have short supply lines. When the Tyrannid take over a world, they convert the entire planet into a biological engine of troop and resource generation. Whatever world they take over reduces the effectiveness of the local forces and strengthens their position.
- This is in addition to any species adaptations and information they may gather BEFORE they consume the entire planet using **[Genestealers](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Genestealer)** and **[Genestealer-hybrids](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Genestealer_hybrid)** to infiltrate the world before its eventual conquest.
- Given the Eldar, in their heyday were a force to be reckoned with, they might have been able to consolidate a section of the Galaxy and hold it against any single Tyrannid threat due to their superior mobility.
- **However, due to the exponentially developing power of the Tyrannids even the Eldar would be no match for their ever-growing numbers due to the six major fleets converging on the galaxy at the same time.**

[image]

*The collective Eldar had one advantage lost to the modern Eldar. **[The Webway](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Webway)**, a means for moving troops quickly across the Galaxy.*

> - The Webway exists as a labyrinth between the Materium and the Warp. It exists as a part of both yet existing in neither. In fact, it has been described as not being a true dimension but instead a complex network of capillaries and arteries. This forms a maze of glowing tunnels making a tapestry of hidden threads that spread between the veil of realspace and warp space. Ultimately, it is a construct that spans the dimensions. Elements of its construction includes complex psychic wards to protect it from being breached and included hyperspatial pathways.
> - Present day Eldar do not fully understand the exact shape or form of the Webway.
>   In the shattered portions of the network exist dead-ends, mazes that trap the unwary, abandoned or destroyed pathways and some even inhabited by Daemons. The doorways into these parts are sealed with runes of power in order to prevent whatever unknown horror populating them from gaining entry into a Craftworld. Knowledge of a Craftworld's placement within the Webway is a secret kept by their Seers.

Comment: :D Was hoping for you... So the fact that I've yet to see anything that could kill the nids I do wonder where the 40k world is going. I assume orks could give the nids a good run for their money..

Comment: No single species could withstand the Tyrannid menace. It would take a consolidated and collective effort of every species working in tandem and in support of each other to even have a chance of winning against them.

Comment: Doesn't it seem like a weird plot device though? Bit like having a superman inside of 40k, yet without any weaknesses.

Comment: No. The Warhammer 40K universe is a nihilistic one. Everyone feels fated to die, in battle, in conflict, in suffering. Some of the species are already dead (Necrons) and still fighting. The Tyrannid can be likened to a natural disaster sweeping through the galaxy, unstoppable, unable to be resisted, yet it makes for compelling tales as each group struggles for survival. It makes a great premise to base a table-top war game on as well...

Comment: @JamieHutber there is even an example of orcs vs nids in the army books. It was evened out for a small time then the nids won. As "simple" as that. nids just outevolutioned the orcs (and bred special liktors to take care of the orc tacticians)